# Using CrateData to index and store 1 millions of PDF files

Tags: lucene, apache-tika, crate

We are looking to find a solution that would allow us to index and store millions of PDF files. We currently use Lucene+Tika but store the PDFs on the file system as blobs (ZODB blobs).

Can Crate.io be used to both index and store large amounts (millions) of PDF files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure, that is one scenario crate is really made for.
Maybe this recent feature request/discussion is also interesting for you: https://github.com/crate/crate/issues/1206